# Jquery conflict while integrating JSXC with Primefaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, primefaces

I'm using:

- Framework: Primefaces 3 (Uses jquery version 1.8.3)
- Server: Glassfish v3
- XMPP Server: Openfire
- XMPP Javascript client: JSXC (Bundled with jquery 2.1.1) (unable to include jsxc tag due to less rep)

I'm having a jsf page "Profile.jsf", and below is my code snippet :

```
<script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.fullscreen.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jsxc.dep.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jsxc.js"></script>

<link href="resources/css/jquery-ui.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/jsxc.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
$(function() {
   jsxc.init({
      root: '/Main',
      xmpp: {
         url: 'http://localhost:7070/http-bind/'
      }
   });
   jsxc.xmpp.login('<my jid>','<my password>');
});
</script>
```

Everything in context to JSXC, works fine. However, some Primefaces components like DateTimePicker errors out in console.

If I exclude `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.ui.min.js`, JSXC chat window never shows up. No javascript error in the console either.

Looks like JSXC was unable to find the `jquery` which is bundled in Primefaces. I may be wrong.

**Question:**

Glad if anybody would let me know, whether this is the issue with me including external jquery build on top of Primefaces own bundled Jquery? Or Problem with JSXC not able to find bundled jquery.

Edit: Also, if there is any workaround so that both jquery version co-exists, would be helpful.

Comment: _"Edit: Also, if there is any workaround so that both jquery version co-exists, would be helpful."_: Put the jsxc parts in an `iframe`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will try it out.

Comment: Tried, but since the iframe includes my jsf page (demo.jsf), the jsxc client is honoring demo.jsf as the parent page and not the Profile.jsf. Which is expected. Any other workaround?